# Сделать JOIN между базой данной и List<>

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ado.net

Есть некоторый List<>, который находится в памяти.

Могу ли я как-нибудь неявно соединить с таблицей из БД(ORM там нет)?

У меня есть идея, создать #таблицу и в нее сделать INSERT из листа, а потом запросом выполнить соединение, но может есть какой-нибудь неявный подход, который сделает это за меня?

Можно еще сгенерить запрос с IN и послать на сервер, но это не универсально, так как IN имеет ограничения на кол-во значений, да и IN по производительности медленнее JOIN.

Comment: Хибер для больших листов создает для листа временную табличку, на которую джойнится. Можете делать аналогично, если ваша ORM так не умеет.

Comment: Можно наоборот: получить данные из БД в другой List, потом два этих списка как угодно связывать. Что лучше, зависит от количества данных в первом List и количества данных, получаемых из БД.

Comment: С другой стороны, создание временной таблицы может быть медленнее, чем `IN`. Так что тестируйте, и именно на ваших данных. Вопросы производительности без тестирования — гадание на кофейной гуще.